# Combine 2 tables into 1 query

Tags: sql-server, ssms-18

I have problem to combining 2 queries into 1 using WITH statement and JOIN.
I've tried that but non of it makes the output the way I wanted.

### Desired Output

[image: the wanted output] ?

### The Separate Outputs

[image: nominal A]

[image: nominal B]

#### JOIN results

[image: combine using JOIN]

Comment: I strongly recommend you learn to format your writing well. Good use of whitespace and linebreaks is *so* important in any written language, and that **includes** code. All left aligned code is *very* difficult to read.

Comment: Good aliasing is also *really* important. `a` is for `TX_DETAILS`? `b` is for `TX_URK`?

Comment: Finally, `varchar` has a length property; not defining it is a really bad habit and will lead to unexpected and undesired behaviour.

Comment: i'm sorry..in my browser it looks good and not all left aligned, yes A is for TX_DETAILS and B for TX_URK

Comment: *"in my browser it looks good and not all left aligned, "* because I editted the code for you and formatted it. It was not [initially](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67074502/1).

Comment: oh.. my bad :(
thank you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH your_first_query AS (
  SELECT ...
)
, your_second_query AS (
  SELECT ...
)
SELECT your_first_query.OFFICE
     , your_first_query.MONTH
     , your_first_query.NOMINAL_A
     , your_second_query.NOMINAL_B
FROM   your_first_query
 INNER
  JOIN your_second_query
    ON your_second_query.OFFICE = your_first_query.OFFICE
   AND your_second_query.MONTH = your_first_query.MONTH
ORDER
    BY your_first_query.OFFICE
     , your_first_query.MONTH
;
```

Comment: thank you, but after trying it i've got error

"Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 81
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Pem' to data type int."

i've check the data and all of it is match and no type int data..
why i get that error?

Comment: i tried to delete the "ON your_second_query.OFFICE = your_first_query.OFFICE"
it worked and not getting error,but the output is the same as what i tried before

Comment: Check the data types of `OFFICE` in both queries.

Comment: i used FULL OUTER JOIN in your code and it work the way i wanted, thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

Hope that following approach would solve your issue:

```
WITH NOMINAL_A_CTE (OFFICE, MONTH, NOMINAL_A)
AS
(
SELECT OFFICE, MONTH, NOMINAL_A
FROM NOMINAL_A_QUERY
),
NOMINAL_B_CTE (OFFICE, MONTH, NOMINAL_B)
AS
(
SELECT OFFICE, MONTH, NOMINAL_B
FROM NOMINAL_B_QUERY
)

SELECT A.OFFICE, A.MONTH, SUM(A.NOMINAL_A), SUM(B.NOMINAL_B)
FROM NOMINAL_A_CTE AS A INNER JOIN NOMINAL_B_CTE AS B
ON A.OFFICE = B.OFFICE AND A.MOTNTH = B.MONTH

GROUP BY A.OFFICE, A.MONTH
ORDER BY A.OFFICE, A.MONTH;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, just looking over your 2 result sets and the desired output you want to Left Outer Join queryresult1 with queryresult2 on their unique keys, Office & Month.  A With clause here does not accomplish anything special:

```
    Select A.Office, A.Month, A.Nominal_A, B.Nominal_B
    From (insert query1 here) A  Left Outer Join
               (Insert query2 here) B on A.Office=B.Office and A.Month=B.Month
```

I noticed your desired result set was missing everything after SLO office, I assume you got tired of typing and you wanted to show them.  If not, you can add a filter to take them out.

Two things that were missing on your original join version,

1. You need the Left Outer Join between the two queries so that the missing offices from query 2 don't cause the data from Query1 to vanish.
2. You need to fully specify the join key as Office=Office AND Month=Month.  By only specifying Month, you were telling SQL to give you ALL COMBINATIONS of offices in Query1 with Query2.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all responses sir!
i already got an answer

```
WITH your_first_query AS (
  SELECT ...
)
, your_second_query AS (
  SELECT ...
)
SELECT your_first_query.OFFICE
     , your_first_query.MONTH
     , your_first_query.NOMINAL_A
     , your_second_query.NOMINAL_B
FROM   your_first_query
 FULL
 OUTER
  JOIN your_second_query
    ON your_second_query.OFFICE = your_first_query.OFFICE
   AND your_second_query.MONTH = your_first_query.MONTH
ORDER
    BY your_first_query.OFFICE
     , your_first_query.MONTH
;
```